# Advance string maniputation in python

Tags: python, string

I am unable to extract the important features from a string which is like this

```
my_string = 'Specifications  Brand - Morisons Baby Dreams Type - Manual Breast Pump Age - 0 months + Color - Assorted  Material - Plastic Publication Year - 2016'
```

I want to extract important specifications in the form of dictionary like the below.

```
general_specs = {
    "Brand" : "Morisons Baby Dreams", 
    "Type" : "Manual Breast Pump", 
    "Age" : "0 months +",
    "Color" : "Assorted",
    "Material" : "Plastic",
    "Publication Year" : "2016"
}
```

I have tried from my end but of no use. Would be happy if someone could help!

PS: Please note the spaces and `-` in the string.

Comment: Is it always going to be this format? Like Brand, and then Type or does it have to be dynamic

Comment: does the keys Brand, Type and Age etc  fixed or change with string. If it's changes with string it's impossible to get the output you needed because there is no difference between keys and values both have spaces

Comment: @SalmanB it is dynamic, this is one of test cases. For one test case I was able to seperate it. But for this It is bit complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions for that:

```
def main():
    my_string = 'Specifications  Brand - Morisons Baby Dreams Type - Manual Breast Pump Age - 0 months + Color - Assorted  Material - Plastic Publication Year - 2016'
    pattern = r'''^Specifications +Brand - (?P<Brand>[a-z ]+)
 +Type - (?P<Type>[a-z ]+)
 +Age - (?P<Age>[a-z0-9\+ ]+)
 +Color - (?P<Color>[a-z ]+)
 +Material - (?P<Material>[a-z ]+)
 +Publication Year - (?P<PublicationYear>[0-9]{4})$'''.replace('\n', '')
    compiled_pattern = re.compile(pattern, re.IGNORECASE)
    result = compiled_pattern.search(my_string)
    print(result.groupdict())
    # Result: {'Brand': 'Morisons Baby Dreams', 'Type': 'Manual Breast Pump', 'Age': '0 months +', 'Color': 'Assorted ', 'Material': 'Plastic', 'PublicationYear': '2016'}
```